# Refer to the object that calls the method with this or with super (java)

Tags: java, methods, reference, this

```
public class Fragile_Base_Class_Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    RandomArrayList randomArrayList = new RandomArrayList();
    randomArrayList.add(12);
    randomArrayList.add(15);
    randomArrayList.add("gosho");
    randomArrayList.add("pesho");
    randomArrayList.add(4);
    randomArrayList.add(3);
    randomArrayList.add(7);
    randomArrayList.add("dsa");
    while (randomArrayList.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println(randomArrayList.getRandomElement());
    }
}
```

So i created a class that extends ArrayList and in it i added a method that gets a random element and then removes it.

```
public class RandomArrayList extends ArrayList {
    public Object getRandomElement() {
        int rnd = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (super.size() - 1));
        Object temp = super.get(rnd);
        super.remove(rnd);
        return temp;
    }
}
```

`int rnd = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (super.size() - 1))` in this line of code like is `super.size` refering to the size of the object with witch i call the method, shoulnd super refer to fields, constructors, methods from superclasses?

Comment: Your explanation is really confusing. Can you try to clarify that or add an example or expected output along with actual output?

Comment: You use `super` in constructors and to call overridden methods - the way you did it doesn't do anything different from if you were to just omit it. You may want to read up on what exactly `super` does.

Comment: `int rnd = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (super.size() - 1))` in this line of code like is `super.size` refering to the size of the object with witch i call the method, shoulnd super refer to fields, constructors, methods from superclasses?

Comment: I don't think you understand inheritance - `super` is the same object as `this`, using `super` just allows you to refer to the same object in a different way. There's only 1 `size` method, so, with or without `super`, that method will be called.

Comment: ok so with `super.size()` i call the method `.size` from the `ArrayList` class, but how does it knows to witch collection i am refering to?

Comment: `super` and `this` is **the same object** - there's only 1 collection.

Comment: Thank you for the patience i think i am starting to see the picture, but can you clarify1 thing you said earlyer " using super just allows you to refer to the same object in a different way" What is "different way" exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144791/discussion-between---and-dukeling).